# shiny R ggplotly Gantt chart configuration

Tags: r, shiny, scrollbar, gantt-chart, ggplotly

I implemented ggplotly gantt chart,
I need to do some changes i.e below:

- for ggplot y axis we want labels inside plot and at the end of every gantt bar,
  i tried using label parameter, but issue was because of long x axis period not seems whole name at the end and seems overlapped name.
- need to add scroll bar for gantt chart ggplotly,
  because we want to show all days of months at axis on x, so because of much data it will be overlapped and not seems good, so need to add scroll bar at bottem like data table view.

we want something like below screenshot, but in proper formatting.
[image]

Comment: Could you please share a minimum reproducible example of your problem along with screenshot?

Comment: please, check image updated, we want something like that with proper view.

Comment: As [amrrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5086335/amrrs) suggested, provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also screenshots of images are not useful.

Comment: 1. As i said need label at the end of every bar without overlap on gantt bars,
2. also need to add scrollbar on ggplotly gantt graph, i.e for long time period range (need zoom view with every days of month axis on x axis)  shows proper.